# How to loop through this array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this array where the first two elements are integers and the third element is another array containing 2 arrays, each with one element. I can loop through the first 2 elements fine but not the third element.

I have tried using a second foreach loop and also a for loop containing a foreach loop.

```
$rows  =  array(1, 2, "qa" => array("q" => array(1,2), "b" => array(3,4)));
$f=1;

foreach($rows as $r) {
   if($f == 1){
      $e = $rows[0];
      $f=$f+1;
   }
   if($f == 2){
      $u = $rows[1];
   }
   if($r == "qa"){
      $c = $value["q"];
      $d = $value["b"];

   }    
} 

echo $e;
echo $u;
print_r($c);
print_r($d);
```

Comment: you need a recursive function to 'loop' through all nested arrays.

Comment: When you pull the variables out, what are you assigning them to?  The real question is what does this array represent, and what are you doing with the information?  If it’s a data structure, it should have a defined structure that you should be able to access things directly, I.e., `$foo = $bar[‘qa’][‘b’][0]`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
$rows  =  array(1, 2, "qa" => array("q" => array(1,2), "b" => array(3,4)));
view($rows);
function view($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if (is_array($value))
            view($value);
        else
            echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_walk_recursive`

```
array_walk_recursive($rows, function($v){echo $v;});
```

DEMO: https://3v4l.org/ITXAu